# convert the BaseForm of 2 (binary data) to an array

Tags: output-formatting, number-bases

How do we convert the BaseForm of 2 (binary data) to a set of number correspond to the their `BaseForm` in terms of an array.

For example,

```
Table[BaseForm[i, 2], {i, 0, 4}]
```

outputs

$${0_2,1_2,10_2,11_2,100_2}$$

How can we make the output to be:

```
{{0,0,0},{0,0,1},{0,1,0},{0,1,1},{1,0,0}}
```

Actually generally we need a larger set of data like

```
Table[BaseForm[i, 2], {i, 0, 2^8}]
```

so it is better to have a systematic method.

Comment: There's no reason to use `BaseForm` other than for display purposes, as far as I understand it. You would want to go back to the original numbers and use `IntegerDigits`, as suggested by @corey979.

Comment: in case you are stuck with it you can pull the number out as the first part of `BaseForm` , eg `IntegerDigits[First@BaseForm[127, 2], 2, 8] -> {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IntegerDigits` is for this:

```
PadLeft[#, 3] & /@ Table[IntegerDigits[i, 2], {i, 0, 4}]
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}

---

Thanks to [march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127529/convert-the-baseform-of-2-binary-data-to-an-array/127531#comment344967_127531) for pointing at the third argument of `IntegerDigits` that works like `PadLeft`:

```
Table[IntegerDigits[i, 2, 3], {i, 0, 4}]
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}

---

But it has to be specified manually, so let's define

```
base2[n_] := Table[IntegerDigits[i, 2, Length@IntegerDigits[n, 2]], {i, 0, n}]
```

to return base-2 for numbers up to `n` in an automated manner. For example:

```
base2[10]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 
>     0}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 
>     0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}}

and

```
base2[2^8]
```

also works.

Comment: It turns out `IntegerDigits` takes a third argument that specifies the padding:  `Table[IntegerDigits[i, 2, 3], {i, 0, 4}]`.